# how to use mq_setattr() in c

Tags: c, linux, ipc, message-queue

I got the required message queue arguments using the following code. Now, I want to change the maxmsg attribute of my queue mq1 using mq_setattr(). But, I do not know how to use that. I read the man page related to this, and tried using but was not successful.
Please help

```
mq1 = mq_open(MY_MQ_NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK , 0666, &att1);

int q;
q = mq_getattr(mq1, &att1);
printf("%d\n", q);
printf("max messages = %ld\n", att1.mq_maxmsg);
```

Comment: You can't do it like that. You need to set it in the `mq_open` call.

Comment: so after this, should I open the queue again? Wouldn't it be an error?

Comment: You can't change the maxmsg value after opening the queue. So what you are trying to do is invalid.

Comment: Alright. But, the default value of max_msg is 10, can I change that before opening the queue?

Comment: Are you trying to change the default value for everyone? Or just the maxmsg for your queue? I assume it is the latter. So what you do is `att1.mq_maxmsg = my_new_value; mq1 = mq_open(MY_MQ_NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK , 0666, &att1);`.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to change that